# <Event.h> library arduino error

Tags: arduino

I am trying to verify and upload a code to arduino mega 2560  but it gives me an error:

```
Arduino: 1.6.12 (Windows 10), Board: "Arduino/Genuino Mega or Mega 2560, ATmega2560 (Mega 2560)"

C:\Users\lenovo\Documents\Arduino\accelerometr_ali\accelerometr_ali.ino:1:19: fatal error: Event.h: No such file or directory

 #include <Event.h>

                   ^

compilation terminated.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\arduino-builder -dump-prefs -logger=machine -hardware C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware -tools C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\tools-builder -tools C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -built-in-libraries C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries -libraries C:\Users\lenovo\Documents\Arduino\libraries -fqbn=arduino:avr:mega:cpu=atmega2560 -ide-version=10612 -build-path C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_442935 -warnings=none -prefs=build.warn_data_percentage=75 -prefs=runtime.tools.avrdude.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -prefs=runtime.tools.avr-gcc.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -verbose C:\Users\lenovo\Documents\Arduino\accelerometr_ali\accelerometr_ali.ino
C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\arduino-builder -compile -logger=machine -hardware C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware -tools C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\tools-builder -tools C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -built-in-libraries C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries -libraries C:\Users\lenovo\Documents\Arduino\libraries -fqbn=arduino:avr:mega:cpu=atmega2560 -ide-version=10612 -build-path C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_442935 -warnings=none -prefs=build.warn_data_percentage=75 -prefs=runtime.tools.avrdude.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -prefs=runtime.tools.avr-gcc.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -verbose C:\Users\lenovo\Documents\Arduino\accelerometr_ali\accelerometr_ali.ino
Using board 'mega' from platform in folder: C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr
Using core 'arduino' from platform in folder: C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr
Detecting libraries used...
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics  -flto -w -x c++ -E -CC -mmcu=atmega2560 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10612 -DARDUINO_AVR_MEGA2560 -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\mega" "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_442935\sketch\accelerometr_ali.ino.cpp" -o "nul"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics  -flto -w -x c++ -E -CC -mmcu=atmega2560 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10612 -DARDUINO_AVR_MEGA2560 -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\mega" "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_442935\sketch\accelerometr_ali.ino.cpp" -o "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_442935\preproc\ctags_target_for_gcc_minus_e.cpp"
C:\Users\lenovo\Documents\Arduino\accelerometr_ali\accelerometr_ali.ino:1:19: fatal error: Event.h: No such file or directory

 #include <Event.h>

                   ^

compilation terminated.

exit status 1
Error compiling for board Arduino/Genuino Mega or Mega 2560.
.
```

the code is for my partner and works fine on his laptop.please help me guys i have to present it tomorrow.

here is the code:

```
 #include <Event.h>
#include <Timer.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
  #include <Password.h>
  #include <LiquidCrystal.h>
  #include <Keypad.h>
  #include<stdio.h>
  #include<string.h>
  #define DEBUG true

//====for gps code=======//
char c;    
 String response;
//============================//
char key;
char buffer[7];
int i;

SoftwareSerial mySerial(10, 11);
Timer t;
//gprs gps==========================================//

int Powerkey = 9;
//accelerometer=========================================//
#include<Wire.h>
const int MPU_addr = 0x68; // I2C address of the MPU-6050
int16_t AcX, AcY, AcZ, Tmp, GyX, GyY, GyZ;
//=====================================================//

#include "pitches.h"

int notes[] = {
  NOTE_A4
};

const int buttonPin53 = 53;
int buttonState53 = 0;

LiquidCrystal lcd(44, 45,46, 47, 48, 49, 50);
//LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 8, 7, 5, 4, 3, 2);
Password password = Password( "1234" );
const byte ROWS = 4; // Four rows
const byte COLS = 3; // Three columns
// Define the Keymap
char keys[ROWS][COLS] = {
  {'1', '2', '3',},
  {'4', '5', '6',},
  {'7', '8', '9',},
  {'*', '0', ' ',}
};
// Connect keypad ROW0, ROW1, ROW2 and ROW3 to these Arduino pins.
byte rowPins[ROWS] = {25, 24, 23, 18}; //connect to the row pinouts of the keypad
byte colPins[COLS] = {28, 27, 26}; //connect to the column pinouts of the keypad
const int buttonPin = 6;
int buttonState = 0;

// Create the Keypad
Keypad keypad = Keypad( makeKeymap(keys), rowPins, colPins, ROWS, COLS );


int t1=0;
int pressed=0;
int afterEvent;
int accident=0;

int pp=0;



void setup() {
  pinMode(Powerkey, OUTPUT);   // initialize the digital pin as an output.  
  power();  
  delay(2000);   


   //while(1)
   //{
  for(int g=0; g<3 ; g++){
      //  sendData( "AT+CGNSINF",1000,DEBUG); 
        getgps();  
        delay(1000);
                         }

  //acceleromeeter====================================//
  Wire.begin();
  Wire.beginTransmission(MPU_addr);
  Wire.write(0x6B);  // PWR_MGMT_1 register
  Wire.write(0);     // set to zero (wakes up the MPU-6050)
  Wire.endTransmission(true);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  //===================================================//
  Serial.print("=== AMS ===");
  delay(2000);
  Serial.print("= WELCOME =");
  delay(2000);
  Serial.print("System loading...");
  Serial.print("Please wait");
  delay(3000);
  Serial.print("AMS Ready!!");


  lcd.print("=== AMS ===");
  delay(2000);
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print("= WELCOME =");
  delay(2000);
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  //lcd.clear();
  lcd.print("System loading...");
  delay(2000);
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print("Please wait");
  delay(3000);
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
 // lcd.clear();
  lcd.print("  AMS Ready!! ");
  delay(3000);


  pinMode(buttonPin53, INPUT);
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);

  lcd.begin(16, 2);

  Serial.begin(9600);
  mySerial.begin(9600); 

if(pp==0){
 lcd.clear();
 delay(1000);
   lcd.print("please enter");
  // delay(1000);
   lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
   lcd.print("your platenumber");
   delay(2000);
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.print("plate number :");
   lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  }

  keypad.addEventListener(keypadEvent); //add an event listener for this keypad
  keypad.setDebounceTime(250);




}

void loop() {
 // getgps();

  t.update();

  // attachInterrupt(5, blink, FALLING);
  if(pp==0){

  i = 0;
  buffer[0] = '\0';
  while( i < sizeof(buffer) - 1)
  {

  key = getChar();
  if (key == '*')
     {
    break;
     }

   else if ( key != NO_KEY)
    {
      buffer[i] = key;
      i++;
      buffer[i]= '\0';
      }

  }
  Serial.println(buffer);

lcd.clear();
lcd.print("success pNb is:");  
lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
lcd.print(buffer);
delay(3000);
lcd.clear();
  password.reset();
  pp=1;
    lcd.print("System ready !!!"); 
       lcd.setCursor(0, 1);

  }






  keypad.getKey();


  //acceleromeeter====================================//

  Wire.beginTransmission(MPU_addr);
  Wire.write(0x3B);  // starting with register 0x3B (ACCEL_XOUT_H)
  Wire.endTransmission(false);
  Wire.requestFrom(MPU_addr, 14, true); // request a total of 14 registers
  AcX = Wire.read() << 8 | Wire.read(); // 0x3B (ACCEL_XOUT_H) & 0x3C (ACCEL_XOUT_L)
  AcY = Wire.read() << 8 | Wire.read(); // 0x3D (ACCEL_YOUT_H) & 0x3E (ACCEL_YOUT_L)
  AcZ = Wire.read() << 8 | Wire.read(); // 0x3F (ACCEL_ZOUT_H) & 0x40 (ACCEL_ZOUT_L)
  Tmp = Wire.read() << 8 | Wire.read(); // 0x41 (TEMP_OUT_H) & 0x42 (TEMP_OUT_L)
  GyX = Wire.read() << 8 | Wire.read(); // 0x43 (GYRO_XOUT_H) & 0x44 (GYRO_XOUT_L)
  GyY = Wire.read() << 8 | Wire.read(); // 0x45 (GYRO_YOUT_H) & 0x46 (GYRO_YOUT_L)
  GyZ = Wire.read() << 8 | Wire.read(); // 0x47 (GYRO_ZOUT_H) & 0x48 (GYRO_ZOUT_L)
  Serial.print("AcX = "); Serial.print(AcX);
  Serial.print(" | AcY = "); Serial.print(AcY);
  Serial.print(" | AcZ = "); Serial.print(AcZ);
  Serial.print(" | Tmp = "); Serial.print(Tmp / 340.00 + 36.53); //equation for temperature in degrees C from datasheet
  Serial.print(" | GyX = "); Serial.print(GyX);
  Serial.print(" | GyY = "); Serial.print(GyY);
  Serial.print(" | GyZ = "); Serial.println(GyZ);
  delay(3);
  if(pp==1){
  if (AcX > 8000 || AcX < -8000 || AcY > 7000 || AcY < -7000 || AcZ < -8000 ) {
    Serial.print(" == == == == == == = accedent happen == == == == == == == == == = ");
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.print("Accident happen!");
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.print("Sound On");
    tone(13, notes[0]);

   t1=0;
   pressed=0;
   accident=1;
    afterEvent = t.after(20000, OnceOnlyTask);

     // attachInterrupt(5, blink, FALLING);
     delay(2000);
      }
  }

  buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);
  if (buttonState == HIGH) {
    password.reset();

        lcd.clear();
    lcd.print("code reset...");
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.print("Enter Again...");
    delay(3000);
      lcd.clear();
       lcd.print("New code :");
        lcd.setCursor(0, 1);

    }


    buttonState53 = digitalRead(buttonPin53);
  if (buttonState53 == HIGH) {
    pp=0;
    lcd.clear();
    password.reset();
     lcd.print("Plate nb reset..");
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.print("Enter Again...");
    delay(3000);
      lcd.clear();
       lcd.print("New Plate nb :");
        lcd.setCursor(0, 1);


  }


}





void keypadEvent(KeypadEvent eKey) {
  switch (keypad.getState()) {
    case PRESSED:
      lcd.print(eKey);
      //Serial.print(" b =  ");
      Serial.print(eKey);
      switch (eKey) {
        case ' ': guessPassword(); break;

        default:
          password.append(eKey);
      }
  }
}


void guessPassword() {
  if(accident==1){
    accident=0;
  if (password.evaluate()) {

    lcd.clear();

   if(t1!=1){


  pressed = 1;

    Serial.print(" valid code");
    lcd.print("VALID code ");
    delay(2000);
    noTone(13);

    password.reset(); //resets password after correct entry
    delay(600);
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.print("Request canceled");
    delay(5000);
    lcd.clear();

      lcd.print("System ready !!!"); 
       lcd.setCursor(0, 1);

   }

   else{
    Serial.print(" Time out");
     password.reset(); 
    lcd.print("Time out ");
    delay(3000);
     lcd.setCursor(0, 1);  
    lcd.print("Request sended");
    delay(3000);
    lcd.clear();

      lcd.print("System ready !!!"); 
       lcd.setCursor(0, 1);



    }
  }


  else
  {

   lcd.clear();
    lcd.print("INVALID Code ");
    password.reset();
    delay(2000);
    lcd.clear();

      lcd.print("System ready !!!"); 
       lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    //resets password after INCORRECT entry


  }
  }else
     {
       lcd.clear();
    lcd.print("No accident !! ");
     delay(2000);
     lcd.clear();

      lcd.print("System ready !!!"); 
       lcd.setCursor(0, 1);

    }


}
void OnceOnlyTask() {
  if(t1==0){
  if(pressed==0){
  Serial.begin(9600);
   lcd.clear();
  Serial.println("Sending request..");
  noTone(13);
   lcd.clear();
  lcd.print("Sending request..");
 // lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1); 
  lcd.print("data upload...");
  delay(2000);
  t1=1;

  //========gps and http request code=======//

getgps();
   //while(1)
   //{
  for(int g=0; g<5 ; g++){
        sendData( "AT+CGNSINF",1000,DEBUG);   
        delay(1000);
                         }
  // }


String latitude=response.substring(46,54); 

 delay(1000);
 String langitude=response.substring(56,64); 

 String pl= buffer;
Serial.print(pl);
int tmp0 = Tmp / 340.00 + 36.53;
//String str(buffer);


mySerial.println("AT+CSQ");
delay(100);

ShowSerialData();// this code is to show the data from gprs shield, in order to easily see the process of how the gprs shield submit a http request, and the following is for this purpose too.

mySerial.println("AT+CGATT?");
delay(100);

ShowSerialData();

mySerial.println("AT+SAPBR=3,1,\"CONTYPE\",\"GPRS\"");//setting the SAPBR, the connection type is using gprs
delay(1000);

ShowSerialData();

mySerial.println("AT+SAPBR=3,1,\"APN\",\"CMNET\"");//setting the APN, the second need you fill in your local apn server
delay(5000);

ShowSerialData();

mySerial.println("AT+SAPBR=1,1");//setting the SAPBR, for detail you can refer to the AT command mamual
delay(5000);

ShowSerialData();

mySerial.println("AT+HTTPINIT"); //init the HTTP request

delay(2000); 
ShowSerialData();

mySerial.println("AT+HTTPPARA=\"URL\",\"http://amsarabia.000webhostapp.com/write_data.php?platenumber="+pl+"&langitude="+langitude+"&latitude="+latitude+"&temp="+tmp0+"\"");// setting the httppara, the second parameter is the website you want to access
delay(1000);

ShowSerialData();

mySerial.println("AT+HTTPACTION=0");//submit the request 
delay(10000);//the delay is very important, the delay time is base on the return from the website, if the return datas are very large, the time required longer.
//while(!mySerial.available());

ShowSerialData();

mySerial.println("AT+HTTPREAD");// read the data from the website you access
delay(3000);

ShowSerialData();

mySerial.println("");
delay(1000);


 lcd.clear();
 // lcd.setCursor(0, 1); 
  lcd.print("request sended");
  delay(3000);
   lcd.clear();

     lcd.print("System ready !!!"); 
       lcd.setCursor(0, 1);



  //========================================//
  }

  }
 }

 //=========method for gps and http request=====//

void ShowSerialData()
{
while(mySerial.available()!=0)
Serial.write(mySerial.read());
}







void getgps(void)
{
   sendData( "AT+CGNSPWR=1",1000,DEBUG); 
   sendData( "AT+CGNSSEQ=RMC",1000,DEBUG); 
}


String sendData(String command, const int timeout, boolean debug)
{
     response = "";    

   mySerial.println(command); 

    long int time = millis();   
    while( (time+timeout) > millis())
    {
      while(mySerial.available())
      {       
         c = mySerial.read(); 
        response+=c;
      }  
    }    
    if(debug)
    {
      Serial.print(response);


    }    
    return response;
}

 //================================//



char getChar()
{
  char key = keypad.getKey();
  if (key != NO_KEY)
  {
     return key;
  }
  else { 
  return NO_KEY;
   }
  }

  void power(void)
{

  digitalWrite(Powerkey, HIGH);
}
```

Comment: Just for curiosity - do you have this library actually installed? This one is definitely not a part of Arduino IDE.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely you did not install the Event Arduino library on your computer.

(Like @KIIV mentioned in the comment on your post).

The error message is saying:

C:\Users\lenovo\Documents\Arduino\accelerometr_ali\accelerometr_ali.ino:1:19: fatal error: **Event.h: No such file or directory**

The Arduino IDE looks inside the folder **Arduino > Libraries** for library files when you include it with <> brackets like you did in your sketch.

Installing a library is quite simple through the Arduino IDE.  Just go to Tools > Manage Libraries and then search for your library and click install.

If this is a library you and your partner wrote yourselves, you'll need to manually put your library folder and files into the Arduino > libraries folder.